# Transaction in a blockchain

Tags: transactions, blockchain, bitcoin

If I make a transaction in a blockchain, does the bitcoin transfer occur only after adding the transaction into the blockchain? If so, it can take time to mine the block and urgent payment cannot be made. So isn't it a disadvantage of blockchain?

Answer (score 1):

It is only a disadvantage if you do not value the advantage of being able to make a monetary transaction with no third party involved (no banks or governments). The entire purpose of blockchain was to be able to move value without relying on a third party who might censor/block transactions, inflate the currency, become compromised, etc. Bitcoin is transparent (verifiable) and decentralized money available to anyone with a computing device and internet connection without restrictions based on your background, nationality, citizenship, or laws.

> If I made a transaction in blockchain, does the bitcoin transfer occur only after adding the transaction into blockchain?

A transaction on Bitcoin is not considered to be final until it has been included in a block. This is important because there are many reasons why it might not be included in a block:

1. Obviously if the transaction is invalid (the user doesn't have the Bitcoin to send, or it contains invalid signature or other invalid information)
2. The fee was too low, and it was rejected by the network
3. If the network is busy, the fee might be too low and it will not be selected by a miner for inclusion in the next block (they will pick transactions with higher fees so they make more money). After 2 weeks Bitcoin Core nodes will kick out stale transactions from the mempool (where they wait to be mined).

> If so, it can take time to mine the block and urgent payment cannot be made. So isn't it a disadvantage of blockchain?

The bigger question here is how much security do you want? If you send someone Bitcoin and they don't even wait until it is included in a block (they see it in their mempool) and they give you the product or service you are buying, they are taking the risk that it might never be mined. Also, after it is included in a block, there is a very small risk of being invalid in the case of a reorganization, see [Chain Reorganization](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Chain_Reorganization). This could happen because of latency issues, for example.

Another risk is a 51% attack, where someone gains a majority of the hashpower on the network, they can change past blocks and if they are able to make a chain with more blocks on it (more proof of work), the network will accept the new chain as the source of truth (longest chain always wins, even if it is different than a previous chain).

So, the more blocks have been mined since the transaction occurred (aka number of [confirmations](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Confirmation)), the more secure it will be from being reversed (or removed) in a reorganization or 51% attack.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider it as a disadvantage in bitcoin blockchain. But it was just the starting point for the technology. In the current scenarios, ethereum has block time of 15 seconds. Which improves the speed of transactions. Also, New consensus mechanisms are helping blockchains to improve this transaction process even more.

Answer (score 0):

In public blockchains take a time to confirm transaction but in consortium blockchains or private blockchain since existence of regulatory entity transaction confirmation is fast.
In public blockchains, type of consensus protocol effects on speed of transaction confirmation for example in Tron blockchain which base on proof of stack ,confirmation process take 1 minute but in Ethereum which base on proof of work ,confirmation process take 6 minutes

Answer (score 0):

someone said: "transaction happens immediately but for some time not all people on the planet know and believe in it".

if you want speed, look at [waves-ng protocol](https://docs.waves.tech/en/blockchain/waves-protocol/waves-ng-protocol#_1-1-problem-statement-and-motivation)